# Fixed position Sidebar through JS

Tags: jquery, position, fixed

I have this sidebar which position is set through JS. Basically, it has to stay in place while the page is scrolled, however, when it reaches the end of the container it goes off. How can I keep the (fixed) div so It doesn't go off the container? 
I'll post the code here and an image to explain better what I'm talking about.

Example: http://www.cosmosgraphicdesign.com/portfolio/work.html?featured

Markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="sidebar">
        <!-- Sidebar Content -->
    </div>

    <div id="mainContent">
        <!-- Main Content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    width: 350px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var mainContent;
var navbarHeight = $(".navbar").height();
var sidebarHeight = $("#sidebar").height()/2;

$(document).on( "scroll", function(){
    mainContent = $(".work").scrollTop() + navbarHeight;

    $("#sidebar").css("top", mainContent);

    if(mainContent => $(".work").height()){
        mainContent = $(".work").scrollTop() + navbarHeight - sidebarHeight;
        $("#sidebar").css("top", mainContent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try setting a `background` to your `.sidebar`..

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm trying to explain: [Image going off container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZHcS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the raw example I've made, if I understand the problem correctly:

```
  var mainContentHeight = $("#mainContent").height();
  var mainContentTop = $("#mainContent").offset().top;
  var sidebarHeight = $("#sidebar").height();
  var sidebar = $("#sidebar");

  $(document).on("scroll", function() {
    //'stick' sidebar to the bottom of main block if we scroll 'too far'
    if ($(window).scrollTop() + sidebarHeight > mainContentHeight + mainContentTop) {
      sidebar.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: mainContentHeight - sidebarHeight + mainContentTop
      });
    }
    //'stick' sidebar to the top of main block 
    else if ($(window).scrollTop() < mainContentTop) {
      sidebar.css({
        position: 'absolute',
        top: mainContentTop
      });
    }
    //fixed sidebar until it won't reach top or bottom of the main content block
    else {
      sidebar.css({
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0
      });
    }
  });
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/6sot6rnw/)

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, but I found another solution before you replied, thanks anyways. 

Here it is: https://codepen.io/jovanivezic/pen/ZQNdag